# Splitting file based on first column's first character and length

Tags: linux, awk, split

I want to split a `.txt` into two, with one file having all lines where the first column's first character is "A" and the total of characters in the first column is 6, while the other file has all the rest. Searching led me to find the `awk` command and ways to separate files based on the first character, but I couldn't find any way to separate it based on column length.

I'm not familiar with `awk`, so what I tried (to no avail) was `awk -F '|' '$1 == "A*****" {print > ("BeginsWithA.txt"); next} {print > ("Rest.txt")}' FileToSplit.txt`.

Any help or pointers to the right direction would be very appreciated.

EDIT: As RavinderSingh13 reminded, it would be best for me to put some samples/examples of input and expected output.

So, here's an input example:

```
#FileToSplit.txt#
2134|Line 1|Stuff 1
31516784|Line 2|Stuff 2
A35646|Line 3|Stuff 3
641|Line 4|Stuff 4
A48029|Line 5|Stuff 5
A32100|Line 6|Stuff 6
413|Line 7|Stuff 7
```

What the expected output is:

```
#BeginsWith6.txt#
A35646|Line 3|Stuff 3
A48029|Line 5|Stuff 5
A32100|Line 6|Stuff 6

#Rest.txt#
2134|Line 1|Stuff 1
31516784|Line 2|Stuff 2
641|Line 4|Stuff 4
413|Line 7|Stuff 7
```

Comment: Could you please post samples of input and expected output in your question, cheers.

Comment: Is your file pipe delimited?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you want to do is use a regex and length function. You don't show your input, so I will leave it to you to set the field separator. Given your description, you could do:

```
awk '/^A/ && length($1) == 6 { print > "file_a.txt"; next } { print > "file_b.txt" }' file
```

Which would take the information in `file` and if the first field begins with `"A"` and is `6` characters in length, the record is written to `file_a.txt`, otherwise the record is written to `file_b.txt` (adjust names as needed)

Comment: You are welcome. Watch for other answers by @anubhava and @ravinderSingh13 -- they will have good ways too. (always more than 1 way to skin-the-cat `:)` For example you can use a single test as `awk '$1 ~ /^A.....$/ {...` as well. However you want to do it.

Answer (score 3):

A non-regex `awk` solution:

```sh
awk -F'|' '{print $0>(index($1,"A")==1 && length($1)==6 ? "file_a.txt" : "file_b.txt")}' file
```

Answer (score 3):

With your shown samples, could you please try following. Since your shown samples are NOT started from `A` so I have not added that Logic here, also this solution makes sure 1st field is all 6 digits long as per shown samples.

```
awk -F'|' '$1~/^[0-9]+$/ && length($1)==6{print > ("BeginsWith6.txt");next} {print > ("rest.txt")}' Input_file
```

---

***2nd solution:*** In case your 1st field starts from `A` following with 5 digits(which you state but not there in your shown samples) then try following.

```
awk -F'|' '$1~/^A[0-9]+$/ && length($1)==6{print > ("BeginsWith6.txt");next} {print > ("rest.txt")}'  Input_file
```

OR(better version of above):

```
awk -F'|' '$1~/^A[0-9]{5}$/{print > ("BeginsWith6.txt");next} {print > ("rest.txt")}' Input_file
```

Comment: Yeah, I had written my examples wrong, got a little bit confused. Thanks for reminding me, got them fixed now.

Comment: @LeoS., Not an issue, we all learn from each other here :) I have updated my 2nd solution now, cheers and happy learning.